# How to enable javascript on xdg-open

Tags: javascript, xdg-open

I am trying to open a url using `xdg-open` but the terminal says,

[image: you don't have javascript enabled]

So how do I enable the javascript?

Comment: You may, if you wish, post a copy/paste of `the actual text in the terminal window`. This facilitates readability! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That message is not from xdg-open. It is from whatever application was used to open the URL. As you are using it over SSH, it isn't opening a graphical web browser, and instead appears to be opening the URL in a console based web browser, which either does not support JavaScript or has the feature disabled.

You will need to use a browser which supports JavaScript, or enable the feature if it is disabled.

Comment: Yup that is my question, how do I enable it?

Comment: I don't know. What browser is it running? As far as I know, lynx supports javascript; but it may not support everything you need. Why aren't you just loading the URL in Safari (it looks like you're on a Mac). If it's not directly accessible, you can tunnel it through ssh, and access it via localhost through the tunnel.

Comment: i am opening the url in the terminal by `ssh` my into the ubuntu server. When i execute `xdg-open <url>` on my local ubuntu, the terminal opens the webpage but not sure why it is giving this issue in the server. I am not using any browser in the my local or server Ubuntu, only `xdg-open`, but it works on my local but gives error on my server which is weird.

Comment: All xdg-open does is open a file or url with the appropriate application. When running locally in a graphical environment on Ubuntu, it opens firefox by default (or chrome or such if you've changed your default browser). If you run it under an SSH session on a remote machine, it still opens in an application. In this case, it is using a console based browser, though I am not sure exactly which browser it is, from the screenshot. But xdg-open itself knows nothing about javascript or enabling it in the browser that gets run.

Comment: oh k so i will have to setup a browser which will be defined as a default browser and then `xdg-open` will open it in that browser. I was under the impression that this command opened the url by itself. ok thanks.